# Clear a textarea with an onclick using using an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, parameters

I am not using a reset button because I have other functions that aren't working either and I need to do it this way to meet program requirements.  I am intentionally not using jQuery.  Everything seems correct to me.

HTML:

```
<script src="js/breaker.js"></script> <!-- it seems to be linked right, but nothing is working -->
<form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false"> <!-- is there something wrong here? -->

<td><textarea id="text" cols="50" rows="10" style="width: 40em; height: 15em;"></textarea></td>

<input type="text" value="0" id="shift" style="width: 4em;"/>

<input type="button" value="Exit value = 3"  onclick ="javascript: clearSetFocus();"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function clearSetFocus() { //functions seems right
     document.getElementById("text").value = "";
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem. Can you try it based on this: http://jsfiddle.net/qjdxj2y2/ - Btw you don't need the `javascript:` part in onclick.

Comment: what does the error console say?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this breaker.js:8
4 Uncaught ReferenceError: clearSetFocus is not defined